# Are hex passwords of a known length easy to crack?

Tags: passwords, hex, cracking

I have the following PHP code:

```
$password = bin2hex (openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (16));
```

It generates a random password like this:

```
fe6fdebf293e5ec5214cc33fbc632d77
```

My question is simple, is the number of possible combinations for this password 16^32, given that hex uses 16 different characters and the length of the password is 32 characters long? Or is it 16^16 given that OpenSSL only generated 16 bytes?

Put a different way, can a hex password like this be more easily cracked due to the nature of hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One byte (eight bits) has 2^8 possible combinations.
16 bytes (8*16 bits) have 2^(8*16) = 2^128  possible combinations.

Representing these combinations in any form (pure binary, hex string, decimal, base64 encoded binary etc) cannot change number of possible combinations.

It doesn't matter if you couny them the other way. 32-digit hex string has the same number of combinations:

32 chars with 16 variants each = 16^32 = (2^4)^32 = 2^(4*32) = 2^128.

Which is not strange, because there is one to one translation from 16 bytes to 32 char hex string and visa versa.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down for me like this. I appears I misunderstood something fundamental about the way hex works. I was thinking because 16 bytes were going in, but 32 characters were coming out, that there might be a way that the work to guess the password could be cut in half somehow. Your explanation makes it clear that's not the case.